# PHP - Cannot Assign String Value to Input with Pattern

Tags: php, html, regex, input

I want to assign mysql_result strings to text inputs, but I can't figure out how the *pattern* attribute messes it up.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id=".$id);

if(mysql_num_rows($q)!=0)
{
    $address = mysql_result($q, 0, 3);
}
```

Sample result would be: **1034 Wildwood Street Stow, OH 44224**.
My *pattern regex* only accepts alpha-numeric characters, period, comma, pound sign, hyphen, and spaces.

```
echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='address' value=".$address." pattern='[a-zA-Z0-9.,#\- ]+' title='Letters, numbers, pound sign, period, and comma only' required>";
```

The *text input* will only display **1034**. I don't know why it ignores the space and the characters after it.

Comment: mysql_num_result ???

Comment: @Progrock It's a mystery.

Comment: @Progrock Typo. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the value attribute.

```
<?php
echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='address' value='$address' pattern='[a-zA-Z0-9.,#\- ]+' title='Letters, numbers, pound sign, period, and comma only' required>";
```

Comment: While not mandatory, I would suggest using a consistent format for HTML attributes, like an XHTML format (just for the attributes).  value="$blah", pattern="blahregex" required="required"